# Automation of user's actions on web pages(sites)

Tags: web, automation

I have a question about working with web on user's side. I need to automatize some user's actions on web pages(sites), but i don't know how to do it. I would have learned this myself, but i don't know what to start with, how to find information that i need. I mean i have no idea what programming language to choose to do this, or how this kind of applications or programs is called. Do i need to learn JavaScript or idk python or c++, or something else? Please, tell me anything you know about this, any information will be useful.

Comment: Are you trying to automate actions on an existing website that you reach, or do you want visitors to your site to have their inputs automated in some cases?

Comment: I am trying to automate actions on an existing website that i reach.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to automate inputs to a website is using [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).

The Selenium website has plenty of information and demonstrations on how to use their software.